# Connecting body parts or clothes problem

Tags: mesh, objects

I need help guys, I kind of need this for a project or something.
First picture is when I haven't connect everything but when I press " Ctr + J " the result is the next picture. I'm really a noob in blender so what seems to be the problem or are there other ways to connect all the body parts / the clothes?
The problem is the eyes and the goggles.

[image: First picture is when I haven't connect everything but when I press " Ctr + J " the result is the next picture. I'm really a noob in blender so what seems to be the problem or are there other ways to connect all the body parts / the clothes?]

[image: This is the result / Second picture]

Comment: you have to apply all modifiers (or make sure all objects have the same modifiers) before joining the objects.

Comment: One last, PS: In your images you could just crop out the windows UI instead of taking the time to black out the file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could parent them. I would add an empty and place it in the center of the object. Then select all the parts of the object and clothes, select the empty last. Then ctrl + P --> object. If you select the empty and move it, the rest will follow.

Comment: Can I ask again another question. If I add an armature in it will it be completely fine? and if I add an armature where should I parent it like the automatic weights.

Comment: @kyouma I don't know much about rigging and armatures, so I can't help you with that.